# Como acomodar un texto cuando se encima con otro en un radio input

Tags: html, angularjs, bootstrap

[image]

Deseo que cuando algún texto de los inputs se encime con el otro, acomodarlo en dos lineas de forma que se vean claramente

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Según el código y las clases que utilizas (col-xs-12, es decir, Bootstrap), lo que debes hacer es crear un nueva fila y sobre ella poner a cada radio en su propio col, es decir:

```
<div class="col-xs-12">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-3"> Clásica </div>
    <div class="col-xs-3"> Hip-hop </div>
    <div class="col-xs-3"> Country/Regional </div>
    <div class="col-xs-3"> Rock/Pop </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comenta si el resultado te funcionó.

Comment: Muchas gracias, resulto tu respuesta, adicionalmente en el div principal aplique el ng-repeat